# Wordpress suddenly stop working

Tags: php, wordpress

My Wordpress website suddenly start to show on index a blank screen, so I drop the DB and import it again and didn't work. Then I tried to reclone the repo and didn't work too. Any suggestions to solve it?

Comment: find the error.log file. where it is depends on your server provider. at the end of the file, there should be a message what has went wrong. if you do understand the messages, post them here.

Comment: thank you... The last line of the error.log is    ...................                  

'[Tue Aug 11 19:07:28.163860 2015] [core:crit] [pid 6284] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:50453] AH00529: /var/www/html/acsite/wp-admin/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/var/www/html/acsite/wp-admin/' is executable'......................                     

the funny thing is that my htaccess is ok, as I checked with the other guys of my team and I the project folder is recursive 777

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include that info rather than in a comment.

Comment: Notice that it complains about htaccess inside wp-admin, that is different from the normal htaccess inside the "root"-folder.

Comment: Thanks a lot Meier. The problem is that I don't know why but htaccess from root was deleted.  weired. But thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Did you install any plugin recently? If yes, make it inactive and try

Comment: No I did not. I was working on code and suddenly stop working. I checked out for the last state of script on git but did not work too